# access value of object sent with eventbus in vue js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, event-bus

i used evntbus to pass data between two components 
in the first one when i click on the button the function submitted is executed like this and i send array of object to the other component

```
submitted(){
  this.products.push(this.product); 
  EventBus.$emit('prod', this.products); 
}
```

---

and in the other component:

```
created(){
  EventBus.$on('prod', function (productObject) {
    console.log('event received!', userObject);
    this.produc = productObject.products
    console.log('The product: ', this.produc)
  }.bind(this));
  console.log('User outside eventbus:', this.produc);
}
```

the problem is that i can't access to objects passed with eventbus in second component can't any one help me ?
the value of productobject is

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22hl7.png)

Comment: can you log `productObject` to the console? are you sure it contains a `products` property or is it an array?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/22hl7.png

Comment: Judging from the log you attached, productObject is an array with one element - as you emit `this.products`, not `this.product`.

Comment: can you explain more please ? i send products from the first component and then in second one i have an  element in my data called produc and i affect to it value recieved from the firsyt one but when i log the console.log('The product: ', this.produc) it is shown undefined

Answer (score 2):

First, it should be `EventBus.$emit('prod', this.products);`, as you emit the event on the EventBus, not on the component.

Second, you pass `this.products` (an array) into Event Bus, but seem to treat it as a single object in the handler function. Besides, you're trying to access some arbitrary value of it (products), apparently thinking that event data object somehow remembers in which variable it was stored. But it's not.

So, based on whether or not you actually need to pass the whole array of products into EventBus, you have two options:

1) if you do need `this.products` elsewhere, access its last element in that other component:

```
EventBus.$on('prod', function(products) {
  this.product = products[products.length - 1]; 
  console.log('The product: ', this.product);
}.bind(this));
```

2) if not, just send the single product and use it directly:

```
EventBus.$emit('prod', this.product);

// ...and in another component
EventBus.$on('prod', function(product) {
  this.product = product; 
  console.log('The product: ', this.product);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: thnx for your response i make a mistake when i copy the code i write it like you said but i can't access value in second component